# Does the electromagnetic force have a range within nuclei (according to the charge of protons) after which it's repulsive effect is negligible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces

I know that the electromagnetic force has an infinite range, but does it have a range within nuclei (according to the charge of protons) after which it's repulsive effect is negligible? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

No. The electrical repulsion between protons goes like $1/r^2$. This is true inside a nucleus just as it is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to believe that it does; it is simply the case that when a proton gets very close to the nucleus, which is not easy to accomplish, the repulsion of like charges is overcome by the strong force.  This force is about 100 times stronger than electromagnetism, has an extremely short range and is only effective within the nucleus. The proton has to give up some of its mass to be accepted into the nucleus, and this mass(its mass defect or binding energy) has to be restored before it can get out again.